# Проблема с кодировкой localhost

Tags: apache, кодировка, сервер

Серв собран собственноручно на ubuntu. В конфигах Apache, .htaccess и header() index.html прописана utf-8, но на деле браузер отображает в 1251. Что и на каком уровне может изменять кодировку?

Comment: Ребят, издеваетесь что-ли?
>  В конфигах Apache, .htaccess и
> header() index.html прописана utf-8

Еще мысли? Правку конфигов сервера не предлагать :)

З.Ы. Перед тесто подключил no-ip DNS. Тестирую уже без него, но может быть он где-то сам кодировку менял?

Comment: Silence Shadow, это тоже уже сделано, правда не в Notepad++. Проблема в том, что браузер распознает как 1251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохраните страницу сайта в notepad++  в формате utf-8, можно даже без ВОМ.

Comment: А что с базой данных? Если она есть, конечно...

Comment: Еще один жирный лом, указать кодировку по умолчанию при помощи пхп:
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')?>  только для этого файл нужно будет обязательно сохранить не хтмл, а с расширением пхп. Обычно пробивает, если проблема с хостингом и сервером. Если не поможет и это, скиньте ссылку на сайт, попробую поковырять =)

Answer (score 1):

В САМОМ начале каждого документа сайта указывайте

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Можете эту строку положить в conf.php и потом подгружать его и все будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

В корень сайта файл .htaccess  с содержимым

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Я все-таки предложу ковырнуть конфиг апача..
там должна быть строка AddDefaultCharset utf-8 или AddDefaultCharset windows-1251
закомментируйте ее вообще, и проблем с кодировкой больше не будет.